# How to save a list of dataframes to csv

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe, export-to-csv

I have a list of data frames which I reshuffle and then I want to save the output as a csv. To do this I'm trying to append this list to an empty data frame:

```
l1=[year1, year2,..., year30]
shuffle (l1)
columns=['year', 'day', 'tmin', 'tmax', 'pcp']
index=np.arange(10957)
df2=pd.DataFrame(columns=columns, index=index)
l1.append(df2)
```

This result in an empty data frames with a bunch of Nans. I don't necessarily need to append my reshuffled list to a dataframe, I just need to save it as a csv, and this is the only way I find yet.

Comment: l1 is just a list of dataframes.

Comment: So you want to create a single csv from all the dataframes?

Comment: user312016, it's a little bit different. Also, in my question I have a list of dataframes, if it was a regular list, it would be easy to save it to csv. Solution for my question is different as well.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think you need [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) with [`to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) if `l1` is `list` of `DataFrames`:

```
print pd.concat(l1).to_csv('filename')
```

Answer (score 4):

An alternative to the chosen answer is to open the CSV and append one dataframe at a time inside a loop. This can be order of magnitude faster depending on the size of data.

```
f = open(filename, 'a')
for df in l1:
    df.to_csv(f)
f.close()
```