# Export a pandas data frame into a csv file ('list' object has no attribute 'to_csv')

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, export-to-csv

Hello I'm trying to export a pandas dataframe in a csv file but I got no clue how to do it. And I got this error 'list' object has no attribute 'to_csv'

```
 import pandas
pandas.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
pandas.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pandas.set_option('display.width', None)
pandas.set_option('display.max_colwidth', -1)

from nba_api.stats.endpoints import playercareerstats

def get_player_current_year(player_id):
  career = playercareerstats.PlayerCareerStats(player_id=player_id)
  player_df = career.get_data_frames()[0]
  return player_df.loc[player_df.SEASON_ID == '2019-20',:]

player_results = []
for player_id in ['203076', '1626157', '203954', '204001', '203999']:
  player_results.append(get_player_current_year(player_id))
for result in player_results:
    print(result)

player_results.to_csv('nbatest.csv')
```

[image: This how the dataframe looks like, is it because I have to merge them?]

This how the dataframe looks like, is it because I have to merge them?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to save a list of dataframes to csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36872851/how-to-save-a-list-of-dataframes-to-csv)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a list of dataframes instead of the dataframe. You can either to save each one of them using `.to_csv()` method or use `pd.concat(player_results, axis=0)` to concatenate them and then save it.

Comment: Can you explain further what I have to do?

Comment: It worked I forgot to put import pandas as pd with your code and worked :D